# Locked out of MySQL

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-18.04, phpmyadmin

So, I was playing around in the settings of phpMyAdmin on my DigitalOcean server. I looked at the security settings and saw the password hashing method dropdown. Being the idiot I was, I was making a social media app, so I thought it should have the best encryption, right? **Wrong.** I set it to SHA256 and *COMPLETELY IGNORED* the part where it said I needed an SSL certificate and now I can't change it. At all. I don't have an SSL certificate. I've tried the good ol' stop-MySQL-and-then-change-the-password trick, but still no dice.

Ubuntu 18.04, MySQL latest. Please help.

Comment: Restore your backup? Rollback to your snapshot? Edit the MySQL configuration yourself, most likely. Few people around here use phpMyAdmin as it's generally faster and more efficient to use the command line directly, at least once you're familiar with MySQL.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yeah, well... You know how I said I'm stupid? I didn't make a backup.